# Evaluating a double sum involving prime numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Evaluate 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{p \leq n} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \ln p \left\{\frac{n}{(p-1)p^k} \right\}$$
where $\{ x\}$ denotes the *fractional part* of $x$, and $p \leq n$ denotes all prime number less than or equal to $n$.

If I let $\epsilon_n$ denote the above limit, then it is trivial to show that $\epsilon_n \geq 0$, since the above limit contains positive integers. On the other hand, I was able to show, with just a bit of manipulation, that $\epsilon_n \geq 1$, though I doubt my work. For those interested, scroll below.

Using the identities $\{x\} + \{y\} \geq \{x+y\}$, $\{\frac{m}{n}\} \leq 1-\frac{1}{|n|}$, and the fact $\sum_{p \leq n} \ln p \sim n$, we have the following

$$\epsilon_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{p \leq n} \ln p \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\{\frac{n}{(p-1)p^k} \right\} \geq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{p \leq n} \ln p \left\{\frac{n}{p-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p^k} \right\} $$

$$= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{p \leq n} \ln p \left\{\frac{n}{p-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p^k} \right\} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{p \leq n} \ln p \left\{\frac{np}{(p-1)^2} \right\}$$

$$ \geq   \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{p \leq n}  \frac{-\ln p}{(p-1)^2} +\ln p \right) \sim 1-\frac{C_n}{n} $$

where $C_n = \sum_{p \leq n}  \frac{\ln p}{(p-1)^2}$. Now, the limit $C_n$ is known to be convergent (by the limit comparison test to the derivative of the prime zeta function), so $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{C_n}{n} \to 0$. Thus $\epsilon_n \geq 1$. Again, I am sure I screwed up somewhere. Support is much appreciated.